# Python-tesseract does not recognize anything

Tags: python, ocr

This is the image that I will import
[image]

My python code

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('/home/milenko/Pictures/Screenshot from 2018-03-06 19-03-19.png')))
```

When I run code

```
python a72.py
```

As an output I got empty line.It does not make any sense.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to tweak your command a little bit using e.g.: other [Page Segmentation Method](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality#page-segmentation-method) As you can see the default value is "Fully automatic page segmentation, but no OSD." so it does not perform orientation and script detection (OSD).

This one gives me some output:

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('image.png'), config='-psm 12'))
```

You can use OpenCV to prepare this image for OCR, e.g:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import Image

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv.imread('/tmp/image.png',0)
ret,thresh = cv.threshold(img, 220, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(thresh, 'gray')
plt.show()

print(pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config='-psm 12'))
```

In the next step you could divide this image into some parts (x-axis, y-axis, trend line) and use OCR for each part separately with the proper PSM value set for each one of them.